# Can I add a field to a doctrine generated database using phpmyadmin?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I would like to add a field to a database table I generated using doctrine and entity files.

This project is on our development server and I have no access to the command line tools I would normally use to update the database schema.

Could I add the field through phpmyadmin and then just make the necessary adjustment to my entity, handler and controller files? Does doctrine do anything that I cannot possible do by manually modifying my files?

Comment: You can do it all manually.

Comment: I tried it. I'm getting a 500 error and have no access to the logs. I tried reverting the change and I still get the 500 error.

Comment: Does you change work locally?  How are you rebuilding the cache?

Comment: Doing the manual operation on database may not seem the correct approach and purpose of using doctrine (database agnostic). You can try same thing on your local server then `orm:shema-tool update --dump-sql` to get the changed sql script then apply same on your database.

Comment: have you tried to activate `app_dev.php` on dev server , like that you can have the error message. go to `app_dev.php` and add your ip address there so you can see errors

Comment: Are you able to clear the cache? Sometime when making DB changes it breaks the meta-data cache.